# Computing MMSE estimator in recursive state dynamics

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation

Consider the $p\times p$ matrix $\pmb{A}$ and suppose $\theta_n, n\ge 0$ are $p$-dimensional vectors we want to estimate according to MMSE criterion.

We have the recursive relation $\theta_n = \pmb{A} \theta_{n-1}, n\ge 1$. Let $\hat{\theta}_0$ be the MMSE estimator of $\theta_0$. Then, since MMSE estimator commutes over affine mappings, the MMSE estimator of $\theta_n$ is given as $\hat{\theta}_n = \pmb{A}^n \hat{\theta}_0$.

Can we still find the MMSE estimate of $\theta_n$ via $\hat{\theta}_n = \pmb{A}^n \hat{\theta}_0$ if $\pmb{A}$ is not invertible?

Comment: I think yes. You simply (and correctly) used the fact that MMSE estimator commutes over affine (or linear) mapping. Whether $A$ is invertible or not does not affect anything.

Comment: @ironX But if $\pmb{A}$ is not invertible, then $\pmb{A}^m$ may become all-zeros for some $m>1$. Wouldn't that render estimation of $\theta_n$ in subsequent $n>m$ times impossible from $\hat{\theta}_0$?

Comment: The thing is: the underlying evolution of $\theta_n$ is also $\theta_n = A \theta_{n-1}$ so the true $\theta_n$ for $n > m$ for some $m$ would also become all zeros. I think the problem you are confusing this with is $\hat{\theta} = A \theta$ where $A$ is the observation matrix, which encodes noise, compression, etc. But in that case, $A$ need not be invertible and usually it isn't (and it's not a problem).